# How to solve this problem with request.get in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

import requests
def pesquisar(string):
    str = string.replace(" ", "+")
    print(str)
    searching = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(str))
    search_result = requests.get(searching).text
    print(search_result)
```

I'm building a function which receives a phrase and searches for youtube videos which contain this words, but I'm getting this error:

> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002452B723100>': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<http.client.HTTPResponse object at
> 0x000002452B723100>?

Any hints of how to correct this?

Comment: Why are you using both `urllib` and `requests`?

Comment: `urrlib.request` is forevermore retired (or should be imo). `requests` is its successor :-)

Answer (score 2):

[requests.get](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.get) accepts a URL. But you are passing it the response of [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) which is not a URL but a [http.client.HTTPResponse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse). See the possible methods for `http.client.HTTPResponse` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects).

Actually, since you already used `urllib.request.urlopen` to get the URL, no need to call `requests.get`. Choose only one. So either through `requests` which is preferrable:

```
...
searching = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(str))
search_result = searching.text
print(search_result)
...
```

Or if you really want to use `urllib`:

```
...
searching = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(str))
search_result = searching.read()
print(search_result)
...
```

Comment: I downvoted because the suggestion for `requests` should come before `urllib` in my opinion

Comment: @rv.kvetch you got a point, I switched them and pointed that `requests` is preferable.

Comment: looks good to me :-)